# Envio de anexo em email PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

estou com um problema neste código, pois quando envio é feito o envio das informações recebo o retorno = 1, porem o anexo não é enviado alguém pode me ajudar?

ENVIO.PHP

```
    $arquivoreal = $_FILES['arquivo'];
    $Nome = $_POST['Nome'];
    $CPF = $_POST['CPF'];

    //Configurações do email, ajustar conforme necessidade
    //==================================================== 
    $email_destinatario ="matheus.henrique@corandini.com.br"; // pode ser qualquer email que receberá as mensagens
    $email_reply = "Supervisão"; 
    $email_assunto = "Curriculo"; // Este será o assunto da mensagem
    //====================================================

    //Monta o Corpo da Mensagem
    //====================================================
    $email_conteudo = "<h1>Envio de Curriculo [SITE]</h1>
                        <p>$Nome CPF: $CPF gostaria de fazer parte do nosso quadro de funcionarios, por isso enviou o curriculo pelo site <br> 
                        (Curriculo em anexo)</p>";
    //====================================================

    //Enviando o email 
    //==================================================== 
        // EnviaEmailCorandini(assunto,msg corpo do email,email,Nome Destinatario,Arquivo em anexo);
    $retorno = EnviaEmailCorandini($email_assunto,$email_conteudo,$email_destinatario,$email_reply,$arquivoreal);


    if($retorno == 1){
        header("Location:index.php");
    }else{
            echo "Falha ao enviar o email";
    }
}
}
```

PHPMailer/index.php

```
 require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

 function EnviaEmail($assunto,$msg,$EmailDestino,$NomeDestino,$NomeArquivo){

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->setLanguage('pt');

    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host         = $host;
    $mail->SMTPAuth     = true;
    $mail->Username     = $user;
    $mail->Password     = $password;
    $mail->Port         = $port;
    $mail->SMTPSecure   = $secure;

    $mail->From     = $from;
    $mail->FromName = $fromName;
    $mail->addReplyTo($from,$fromName);

    $mail->addAddress($EmailDestino,$NomeDestino);
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->CharSet      = 'utf-8';
    $mail->WordWrap     = 70;
    $mail->Subject      =  $assunto;
    $mail->Body         = $msg;
    $mail->AddAttachment($NomeArquivo);           
    $send = $mail->Send();

    if($send)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Ele está retornando um porque de fato o e-mail foi enviado. De um echo nesse $nomeArquivo e tente acessar o arquivo pelo navegador. Lembre-se que para o phpmailer anexar é necessário o caminho absoluto do arquivo.

Comment: A questão é confusa, você usa a classe EnviaEmailCorandini mas colou o código da classe EnviaEmail. Ali você tem o último parâmetro $NomeArquivo mas está enviado um Array $arquivoreal = $_FILES['arquivo'], se quiser só o nome do arquivo seria $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], faltou pesquisar o manual: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pela descrição do código você precisa enviar o nome do arquivo, alterando a seguinte linha:

```
$arquivoreal = $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'];
```

So que assim o anexo vai com o nome temporário.

Você pode corrigir de duas formas:

1. Mover o arquivo para algum local temporário com o nome correto:

   $tmp_dir = $path_parts = pathinfo($_FILES['tmp_name']);
   $arquivoreal = $tmp_dir['dirname'] . '/' . $_FILES['name'];
   move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['tmp_name'], $arquivoreal);

Após o envio é necessário remover o arquivo:

```
$retorno = EnviaEmailCorandini(...);
unlink($arquivoreal);
```

2. Ou classe EnviaMail, fazer uso do segundo parâmetro do método AddAttachment() como abaixo, mas para isso será necessário alterar a chamada a função:

   // alterar a chamada
   $retorno = EnviaEmailCorandini($email_assunto,$email_conteudo,$email_destinatario,$email_reply, $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['arquivo']['name']);

   // alterar a definição da função
   function EnviaEmail($assunto,$msg,$EmailDestino,$NomeDestino,$NomeArquivo, $NomeRealDoArquivo){

   // alterar a inclusão do anexo
   $mail->AddAttachment($NomeArquivo, $NomeRealDoArquivo);

Comment: Então, fiz desta forma e deu certo, porem vai como arquivo .tmp como eu poderia fazer para mandar o arquivo na mesma extensão e nome no qual foi "postado"

Comment: @MatheusSouza, editei a resposta para contemplar a mudança de nome do anexo.